# Playwright - Cucumber - Javascript: How to run features through NPX command

Tags: javascript, playwright, cucumberjs

Hi: I want to run Cucumber features through npx command, but I cannot.

This is the command that I use: `npx playwright tests:chrome --grep @POC`

Here the **Playwright config file**:

```
const config = { 
    timeout: 3000,
    actionTimeout: 1500,
    //workers: 2, //for parallel testing
    retries: 2,
    testDir: 'features/**/*.feature', 
    use: {
        headless: false, //true
        viewport: { width: 1920, height: 1080 }, //1280x720
        launchOptions: {
            slowMo: 1000,
        },
        video:"off",
        screenshot: 'only-on-failure',
    },
    projects: [
        {
            name: 'Chromium',
            use: { browserName: 'chromium'},
        },
        {
            name: 'Firefox',
            use: { browserName: 'firefox'},
        },
        {
            name: 'Webkit',
            use: { browserName: 'webkit'},
        },
    ],
};

module.exports = config;
```

This is my **package.json** file:

```
{
  "name": "automation-testing",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Testing Automation Framework with Playwright and CucumberJs.",
  "main": "config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "tests:chrome": "playwright test --config=playwright.config.js --project=Chromium",
    "tests:firefox": "playwright test --config=playwright.config.js --project=Firefox",
    "tests:webkit": "playwright test --config=playwright.config.js --project=Webkit",
    "tests:cucumber": "./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js --require cucumber.js --require step-definitions/**/*.js --require features/**/*.js -f json:cucumber_report.json",
    "report": "node reporter.js"
  },
  "author": "NN",
  "license": "ISC",
  "homepage": "https://bitbucket.org/maritzmotivation/rpp-automation-testing#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "@cucumber/cucumber": "^8.8.0",
    "@playwright/test": "^1.27.1",
    "chai": "^4.3.7",
    "cucumber-html-reporter": "^5.5.0",
    "playwright": "^1.27.1",
    "prettier": "^2.8.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "playwright-expect": "^0.1.2"
  }
}
```

When I run thorough Cucumber it works (`npm run tests:cucumber -- --tags "@MyTag"`), but when I try to run this with npx (`npx playwright tests:chrome --grep @MyTag`) it displays error:

```
error: unknown command 'tests:chrome'
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen the possibility of running the cucumber playwright tests through the playwright test runner
I can only suggest using the config file with the data you want to pass to the tests and read during test initialization (you can probably pass the filename and location somehow using cmd parameter)

like testconfig.json

```
{
 "browser": "chrome",
 ...
}
```

And then in BeforeAll step you can read the file and launch the browser needed with the needed params

```
  BeforeAll(async () => {
    const config = <read the config file here>
    console.log("Launching browser...");
    if (config.browser == "chrome") {
       browser = await chromium.launch({
          headless: config.headless,
       });
    }
    ...
    ...
  });
```

See also how to pass params to the World
[Documentation](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/main/docs/cli.md)

OR using cucumber profiles [Documentation of profiles](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/main/docs/cli.md)

I have the following script (one of many) defined in package.json

```
"debug-pw": "npx cucumber-js -p test_runner --tags @debug"
```

then you will be able to playwright debugging feature

```
$env:PWDEBUG=1
npm run debug-pw
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: sorry, I was looking at how to debug playwright cucumber tests with the playwright test debugger and it requires also npx. So now after careful reading of the problem added a suggestion on how to resolve the problem